# jquery ajax: not serialize current textarea state

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So, i want to make an ajax with jquery that send the values inside a textarea using method post.
The textarea is inside a form with a button. When the button being clicked, i want to change the value of the other element by the value of the textarea.

The problem is:
Everytime i click the button, the serialize() function is not capturing the current textarea value. Instead, it captures the previous textarea value.
So, this is the example (in step):

1 -> i change the textarea value into "one", then click the button
response: the ajax is success but nothing is changed. (i expect other element value to change into "one")

2 -> i change the textarea value into "two", then click the button
response: the ajax is success but the element's value that i expected to change into "two", changes into "one" instead.

3 -> i change the textarea value into "three", then click the button
response: the ajax is success but the element's value that i expected to change into "three", changes into "two" instead.

and so on.

**Here is the HTML Form code**

```
<form action="/" id="replies">
   <div class="input-group">
     <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
     </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Here is the element i want to change the value**

```
<ul class="chat" id="result" name="result"></ul>
```

**Here is the jquery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var request;
  $( "#replies" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }

    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "sys/callback.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $( "#result" ).append( response );
        console.log("It wroks!");
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("Error boss!");
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    request.always(function () {
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
  });
});
```

**Here is the sys/callback.php code**

```
<?php
$toreturn = "";
if (isset($_POST['editor1'])) {
    $toreturn .= "<li>".$_POST['editor1']".</li>";
    echo $toreturn;
} else {
    echo "Retrieve Failed!";
}
?>
```

Question: How to make it work like what i expected in the example i gave?

That's all, thanks for your help :)
i really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you monitor the request/response using your browser's web developer/inspector tool? This would give you a better indicator of what's being sent.

Comment: @Mikey yes i did, and the problem is indeed in the serialize(). when i console.log(serializedData) on the first click, it returns editor1 = (exactly like my example above)

Comment: It works for me with jquery 3.1.1.  You have the . in the wrong spot in your PHP, but that is not related.  Eliminate some complexity for testing purposes: on submit, simply try `alert($form.serialize())` and see what gets alerted.

Comment: @AlanP. just tried the alert($form.serialize()); and it returns "editor1=" for the first click (i typed "one" on the textarea).

Comment: Here is a working codepen, maybe it will help you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpGBxV?editors=1010#0

Comment: thanks @AlanP. i know why this thing happen. It is because i use CKeditor for my textarea, after i remove it, everything work fine :)